# How to create a security certificate for my python app

Tags: python, security, pyinstaller

Recently I made an app using python. When I ran it in my laptop windows smart screen is saying that this app is not secure. I made the executable using pyinstaller. The app has no malware in it.What to do now?

Answer (score -2):

Usually you can just click on `more info` and click `Run Anyway` at the bottom

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But I want if other people use my software then they should not get this message. Because if they get this message they would think that my software contains virus